# Set optional action parameter to null by default?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with an MVC action I'm trying to write.  I want a model to be supplied as an optional parameter to the action so that the model can be fetched from TempData instead if there is no model supplied.  So I have the following:

```
public ActionResult Page1(TestFormViewModel model = null)
{
    if (model == null)
    {
        model = TempData["model"] as TestFormViewModel;
    }

    return View("Page1", model);
}
```

But every time I try this, the model is a newly instantiated copy of the TestFormViewModel class, instead of being null.  How can I make the parameter null when there is no model supplied?

Comment: Is this an HTTP Get, Put, or Post?

Comment: I'm new to MVC, but I suspect this might not be possible.  It might be that MVC first instantiates an instance of TestFormViewModel, then copies all the parameters into the model.  I haven't found an MVC life cycle document that goes into the detail of how the parameters are hydrated.

Comment: How does TempData get set in this case?  Are you callin this from a Redirect?  If so, it looks a lot like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833360/

Comment: @gnack, You should debug and check that you are getting model as null, if yes then check what you are getting back from tempdata['model']. I think there is no issue in code.

Comment: @makwana.a I should have mentioned in the question, but I have debugged already and model is not null right from the start, it's a newly created instance of the TestFormViewModel class.

Comment: @MobyDisk you might be right, maybe it's not possible. I've found a better approach to my overall problem now anyway so I can avoid this requirement altogether, but I'm definitely still curious. TempData by the way is being set in another action, which then redirects to the action in the question.

Comment: I invite you to post your alternative approach as an answer.  I am curious since I am learning MVC as well.

Comment: It's too specific to my own project to be useful as an answer unfortunately - it doesn't solve the problem in the question, it just uses a different approach.